# Function converted from Lua to Java has wrong results

Tags: java, lua

I've tried to port these 2 functions from Lua to Java (bspline2D and bspline3D), but they doen't work. The output is completely different, and I can't figure out why.

I've already tried messing with the array numbers, the subdivision value, the for loops, and everything that came up my head.

The test provided should give numbers that are totally different one another, but they're not.

These are the Java results:

bspline2D

```
0.0, 0.0, 0.0
-1.0, 0.0, 0.0
-1.0, 0.0, 0.0
-1.0, 0.0, 0.0
-1.0, 0.0, 0.0
0.0, 0.0, 0.0
0.0, 0.0, 0.0
0.0, 0.0, 0.0
0.0, 0.0, 0.0
```

bspline3D

```
-2.0, 0.0, 0.0
-1.0, 0.0, 0.0
-1.0, 0.0, 0.0
0.0, 0.0, 0.0
0.0, 0.0, 0.0
```

...which are clearly wrong.

These are the outputs from the Lua version, the *correct* ones.

bspline2D

```
0, 0
-0.75, 0
-0.5, 0
-0.25, 0
0, 0
0.24739583, 0.0026041667
0.47916666, 0.020833334
0.6796875, 0.0703125
0.8333333, 0.16666667
0.9270833, 0.31770834
0.9583333, 0.5
0.9270833, 0.6822917
0.8333333, 0.8333333
0.6796875, 0.9296875
0.47916666, 0.9791667
0.24739583, 0.9973958
0, 1
```

bspline3D

```
0, 0, 0
0.24739583, 0.0026041667, 0
0.47916666, 0.020833334, 0
0.6796875, 0.0703125, 0
0.8333333, 0.16666667, 0
0.9270833, 0.31770834, 0
0.9583333, 0.5, 0
0.9270833, 0.6822917, 0
0.8333333, 0.8333333, 0
0.6796875, 0.9296875, 0
0.47916666, 0.9791667, 0
0.24739583, 0.9973958, 0
0, 1, 0
-0.25, 1, 0
-0.5, 1, 0
-0.75, 1, 0
-1, 1, 0
-1.25, 1, 0
-1.5, 1, 0
-1.75, 1, 0
-2, 1, 0
```

I've been scratching my head for days on this, and I have just no ideas, so I thought maybe someone here at StackOverflow would.

Here's the Java version that needs to be fixed:

```
    public static List<Vector3> bspline2D(Vector3[] pointz, int subdivision) {
        ArrayList spline = new ArrayList();
        int pointsNumber = pointz.length;
        Vector3[] points = new Vector3[pointsNumber + 4];
        System.arraycopy(pointz, 0, points, 2, pointsNumber);
        points[1] = points[2].add(points[2].minus(points[3]));
        points[0] = points[1].add(points[1].minus(points[2]));
        points[pointsNumber + 2] = points[pointsNumber - 3].add(points[pointsNumber - 3].minus(points[pointsNumber - 4]));
        points[pointsNumber + 3] = points[pointsNumber].add(points[pointsNumber].minus(points[pointsNumber - 3]));
        spline.add(pointz[0]);

        for(int i = 1; i < pointsNumber - 1; ++i) {
            double[] a = new double[4];
            double[] b = new double[4];
            a[0] = (-points[i - 1].x + 3.0D * points[i].x - 3.0D * points[i + 1].x + points[i + 2].x) / 6.0D;
            a[1] = (3.0D * points[i - 1].x - 6.0D * points[i].x + 3.0D * points[i + 1].x) / 6.0D;
            a[2] = (-3.0D * points[i - 1].x + 3.0D * points[i + 1].x) / 6.0D;
            a[3] = (points[i - 1].x + 4.0D * points[i].x + points[i + 1].x) / 6.0D;
            b[0] = (-points[i - 1].y + 3.0D * points[i].y - 3.0D * points[i + 1].y + points[i + 2].y) / 6.0D;
            b[1] = (3.0D * points[i - 1].y - 6.0D * points[i].y + 3.0D * points[i + 1].y) / 6.0D;
            b[2] = (-3.0D * points[i - 1].y + 3.0D * points[i + 1].y) / 6.0D;
            b[3] = (points[i - 1].y + 4.0D * points[i].y + points[i + 1].y) / 6.0D;

            for(int j = 0; j < subdivision; ++j) {
                double t = j / subdivision;
                spline.add(new Vector3((a[2] + t * (a[1] + t * a[0])) * t + a[3], (b[2] + t * (b[1] + t * b[0])) * t + b[3]));
            }
        }

        return spline;
    }

    public static List<Vector3> bspline3D(Vector3[] pointz, int subdivision) {
        ArrayList spline = new ArrayList();
        int pointsNumber = pointz.length;
        Vector3[] points = new Vector3[pointsNumber + 4];
        System.arraycopy(pointz, 0, points, 2, pointsNumber);
        points[1] = points[2].add(points[2].minus(points[3]));
        points[0] = points[1].add(points[1].minus(points[2]));
        points[pointsNumber + 2] = pointz[pointsNumber - 1].add(pointz[pointsNumber - 1].minus(pointz[pointsNumber - 2]));
        points[pointsNumber + 3] = points[pointsNumber].add(points[pointsNumber].minus(pointz[pointsNumber - 1]));
        spline.add(points[0]);

        for(int i = 1; i < pointsNumber - 1; ++i) {
            double[] a = new double[4];
            double[] b = new double[4];
            double[] c = new double[4];
            a[0] = (-points[i - 1].x + 3.0D * points[i].x - 3.0D * points[i + 1].x + points[i + 2].x) / 6.0D;
            a[1] = (3.0D * points[i - 1].x - 6.0D * points[i].x + 3.0D * points[i + 1].x) / 6.0D;
            a[2] = (-3.0D * points[i - 1].x + 3.0D * points[i + 1].x) / 6.0D;
            a[3] = (points[i - 1].x + 4.0D * points[i].x + points[i + 1].x) / 6.0D;
            b[0] = (-points[i - 1].y + 3.0D * points[i].y - 3.0D * points[i + 1].y + points[i + 2].y) / 6.0D;
            b[1] = (3.0D * points[i - 1].y - 6.0D * points[i].y + 3.0D * points[i + 1].y) / 6.0D;
            b[2] = (-3.0D * points[i - 1].y + 3.0D * points[i + 1].y) / 6.0D;
            b[3] = (points[i - 1].y + 4.0D * points[i].y + points[i + 1].y) / 6.0D;
            c[0] = (-points[i - 1].z + 3.0D * points[i].z - 3.0D * points[i + 1].z + points[i + 2].z) / 6.0D;
            c[1] = (3.0D * points[i - 1].z - 6.0D * points[i].z + 3.0D * points[i + 1].z) / 6.0D;
            c[2] = (-3.0D * points[i - 1].z + 3.0D * points[i + 1].z) / 6.0D;
            c[3] = (points[i - 1].z + 4.0D * points[i].z + points[i + 1].z) / 6.0D;

            for(int j = 1; j < subdivision; ++j) {
                double t = j / subdivision;
                Vector3 sp = new Vector3();
                sp.x = (a[2] + t * (a[1] + t * a[0])) * t + a[3];
                sp.y = (b[2] + t * (b[1] + t * b[0])) * t + b[3];
                sp.z = (c[2] + t * (c[1] + t * c[0])) * t + c[3];
                spline.add(sp);
            }
        }

        return spline;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector3[] v = new Vector3[] {new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 1, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0)};

        System.out.println("\nbspline2D");
        for(Vector3 v3 : bspline2D(v, 4)) {
            System.out.println(v3.x + ", " + v3.y + ", " + v3.z);
        }

        System.out.println("\nbspline3D");
        for(Vector3 v3 : bspline3D(v, 4)) {
            System.out.println(v3.x + ", " + v3.y + ", " + v3.z);
        }
    }
```

And here's the Lua version:

```
function M.bspline2D(points, subdivision)
  local spline = {}
  local wbvector2 = dofile('wbvector3.lua')
  local pointsNumber = #points

  -- extend the points array
  points[0]                = wbvector2.add(points[1], wbvector2.minus(points[1], points[2]))
  points[-1]               = wbvector2.add(points[0], wbvector2.minus(points[0], points[1]))
  points[pointsNumber + 1] = wbvector2.add(points[pointsNumber], wbvector2.minus(points[pointsNumber], points[pointsNumber - 1]))
  points[pointsNumber + 2] = wbvector2.add(points[pointsNumber + 1], wbvector2.minus(points[pointsNumber + 1], points[pointsNumber]))

  -- Interpolation
  local index = 1
  spline[index] = points[1] -- first point
  for i = 0, pointsNumber - 1 do
    local a = {} -- compute the third order coefficients for x
    local b = {} -- compute the third order coefficients for y
    a[1] = (-points[i-1].x + 3 * points[i].x - 3 * points[i+1].x + points[i+2].x) / 6.0;
    a[2] = (3 * points[i-1].x - 6 * points[i].x + 3 * points[i+1].x) / 6.0;
    a[3] = (-3 * points[i-1].x + 3 * points[i+1].x) / 6.0;
    a[4] = (points[i-1].x + 4 * points[i].x + points[i+1].x) / 6.0;
    b[1] = (-points[i-1].y + 3 * points[i].y - 3 * points[i+1].y + points[i+2].y) / 6.0;
    b[2] = (3 * points[i-1].y - 6 * points[i].y + 3 * points[i+1].y) / 6.0;
    b[3] = (-3 * points[i-1].y + 3 * points[i+1].y) / 6.0;
    b[4] = (points[i-1].y + 4 * points[i].y + points[i+1].y) / 6.0;
    for j = 1, subdivision do
      index = index + 1
      spline[index] = {}
      local t = j / subdivision
      spline[index].x = (a[3] + t * (a[2] + t * a[1])) * t + a[4]
      spline[index].y = (b[3] + t * (b[2] + t * b[1])) * t + b[4]
    end
  end
  return spline
end

function M.bspline3D(points, subdivision)
  local spline = {}
  local wbcore = require('wbcore')
  local wbvector3 = require('wbvector3')
  local pointsNumber = wbcore.tablelength(points)

  -- extend the points array
  points[0]                = wbvector3.add(points[1], wbvector3.minus(points[1], points[2]))
  points[-1]               = wbvector3.add(points[0], wbvector3.minus(points[0], points[1]))
  points[pointsNumber + 1] = wbvector3.add(points[pointsNumber], wbvector3.minus(points[pointsNumber], points[pointsNumber - 1]))
  points[pointsNumber + 2] = wbvector3.add(points[pointsNumber + 1], wbvector3.minus(points[pointsNumber + 1], points[pointsNumber]))

  -- Interpolation
  local index = 1
  spline[index] = points[1] -- first point
  for i = 1, pointsNumber - 1 do
    local a = {} -- compute the third order coefficients for x
    local b = {} -- compute the third order coefficients for y
    local c = {} -- compute the third order coefficients for z
    a[1] = (-points[i-1].x + 3 * points[i].x - 3 * points[i+1].x + points[i+2].x) / 6.0;
    a[2] = (3 * points[i-1].x - 6 * points[i].x + 3 * points[i+1].x) / 6.0;
    a[3] = (-3 * points[i-1].x + 3 * points[i+1].x) / 6.0;
    a[4] = (points[i-1].x + 4 * points[i].x + points[i+1].x) / 6.0;
    b[1] = (-points[i-1].y + 3 * points[i].y - 3 * points[i+1].y + points[i+2].y) / 6.0;
    b[2] = (3 * points[i-1].y - 6 * points[i].y + 3 * points[i+1].y) / 6.0;
    b[3] = (-3 * points[i-1].y + 3 * points[i+1].y) / 6.0;
    b[4] = (points[i-1].y + 4 * points[i].y + points[i+1].y) / 6.0;
    c[1] = (-points[i-1].z + 3 * points[i].z - 3 * points[i+1].z + points[i+2].z) / 6.0;
    c[2] = (3 * points[i-1].z - 6 * points[i].z + 3 * points[i+1].z) / 6.0;
    c[3] = (-3 * points[i-1].z + 3 * points[i+1].z) / 6.0;
    c[4] = (points[i-1].z + 4 * points[i].z + points[i+1].z) / 6.0;
    for j = 1, subdivision do
      index = index + 1
      spline[index] = {}
      local t = j / subdivision
      spline[index].x = (a[3] + t * (a[2] + t * a[1])) * t + a[4]
      spline[index].y = (b[3] + t * (b[2] + t * b[1])) * t + b[4]
      spline[index].z = (c[3] + t * (c[2] + t * c[1])) * t + c[4]
    end
  end
  return spline
end

local v = {{x = 0, y = 0, z = 0}, {x = 1, y = 0, z = 0}, {x = 1, y = 1, z = 0}, {x = 0, y = 1, z = 0}}

print()
print("bspline2D");
for _, v3 in ipairs(M.bspline2D(v, 4)) do
    print(v3.x .. ", " .. v3.y .. ", " .. v3.z)
end

print()
print("bspline3D");
for _, v3 in ipairs(M.bspline3D(v, 4)) do
    print(v3.x .. ", " .. v3.y .. ", " .. v3.z)
end
```

Comment: You haven't told us what the numbers _should_ be, or shown the code that invokes the methods, including the arguments passed.  Without that we really cannot help you.

Comment: Well yea I forgot to add the numbers, will do it now, but I did add the test code, it's at the end of their respective snippets.